reserve space for a legend in pyplot while fixing plot size and x-axis position
here are two of my plotting functions and example use:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def set_legend(ax, item_count, title=None):
    legend = ax.legend(
        title=title,
        loc='upper center',
        bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.1),
        ncol=item_count,
        frameon=False,
        prop={'size': 6}
    )
    legend.get_title().set_fontsize('8')
    return ax
  
def generate_plot_base():
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(6, 2.71), tight_layout={'pad': 0})
    return ax

ax = generate_plot_base()
ax.plot([], [], label='Label 1', color='blue')  # Toy labels
ax.plot([], [], label='Label 2', color='orange')
ax.plot([], [], label='Label 3', color='green')
ax = set_legend(ax, 3, title="Example Legend") # if you comment out the x-axis goes down
plt.show()

the thing is - when I don't have a legend, the size of the plot is the figsize.
but, when I add a legend without a title, the bottom of the plot expands to accommodate the legend. if I add a legend title, it expands more (or if I use tight_layout, it stays the same but the x-axis moves upwards within the plot).
instead, I want to add extra space between the bottom and the x-axis, so that if I add a legend (with or without a legend title), both the area of the plot (pixel dimensions) and the location of the axis will stay the same, since there is already enough free area.
I tried experimenting with tight_layout and subplot_adjust, but I can't get the behavior that I describe here.

Is "expends" a typo? Did you mean "expands"? Also, just to be clear, when adding a legend, do you want the pixel dimensions of the resulting image to change or stay the same? Finally, your current code doesn't really work, as there is no data for the legend to correspond to. Please update it to include sample data that reproduces your issue.

thank you, improved the question based on your comments

tight_layout has a rect parameter which tells it what area of the figure to fit the subplots and other artists in.  This requires some manual trial and error, but rect=(0, 0.12, 1, 1) seems to work well for the current example.
We can tell tight layout to ignore the legend by setting legend.set_in_layout(False).
I also made the figure facecolor grey, just so it's easier to see the distance between the axes and the figure in the example plots.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def set_legend(ax, item_count, title=None):
    legend = ax.legend(
        title=title,
        loc='upper center',
        bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.1),
        ncol=item_count,
        frameon=False,
        prop={'size': 6}
    )
    legend.set_in_layout(False)
    legend.get_title().set_fontsize('8')
    return ax
  
def generate_plot_base():
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(6, 2.71), tight_layout={'pad': 0, 'rect': (0, 0.12, 1, 1)}, facecolor='lightgray')
    return ax

ax = generate_plot_base()
ax.plot([], [], label='Label 1', color='blue')  # Toy labels
ax.plot([], [], label='Label 2', color='orange')
ax.plot([], [], label='Label 3', color='green')
ax = set_legend(ax, 3, title="Example Legend")
plt.show()

With legend:

Without legend:

